# Use of binary variables in LP problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I can't figure out how to write the following condition to an LP.

I have four nonnegative variables: $X_A$, $X_B$, $X_C$, and $X_D$.

The condition which should be satisfied is this:

If $X_A$ and $X_B$ have positive coefficients in the optimal solution then, $X_C$ shoud have $0$ coefficient in the optimum.

I guess, I should introduce binary variables, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I guess it is equivalent saying that the 3 variables cannot all  have positive coefficients in the optim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binary variables $y_A$ and $y_B$ that equal $1$ if and only if $X_A$ and $X_B$ are strictly positive (respectively).

Then add the following constraints to your LP:
\begin{align*}
&X_A\le M\,y_A\\
&X_B\le M\,y_B\\
&X_C\le M\,(2-y_A-y_B)
\end{align*}

M is a large constant. The first two constraints activate the binary variables $y_A$ and $y_B$ if $x_A$ and $x_B$ are strictly positive. The last constraint ensures what you want: if $X_A$ and $X_B$ are strictly positive, then $y_A=y_B=1$, and the right hand term equals $0$, imposing $X_C=0$.

Comment: But, what if for example $X_A$ is $0$, but $y_A$ is not?

Comment: That is a good point. You can deal with this by introducing an extra term in your objective function, e.g. $\sum_{i=A,B} y_i$. Assuming it is a minimization problem, the solver will always set $y_i$ to $0$ unless it absolutely can't (i.e. when $X_i>0$).